# Tell Iron Router not to intercept a link

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm moving quite a large application to Iron Router. On the client side, all unknown routes are redirected to `/404`. In addition, some routes are managed from the server side - for example `/static`, that just displays a static page via middleware. The problem is that Iron Router now intercepts all link clicks - so when I click a link to `/static`, the action is prevented, browser does not display the server response for that address, and user is redirected to `/404` instead.

How do I prevent such behavior? Is there a way to tell Iron Router not to intercept a certain link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell iron router which links it should hook into with the css selector:

```
IronLocation.configure({
    'linkSelector' : 'a[href], a:not([skipir])'
});
```

Then you could have `<a href=".." skipir>Skip this route</a>`